# Yarn does not see workspaces

Tags: yarnpkg, workspace, monorepo

I have the following configuration in a root workspace. The strange thing is that for backend it works, but for frontend - doesn't, no matter how I rename this

```
{
    "private": true,
    "name": "root",
    "workspaces": [
        "packages/frontend",
        "packages/backend"
      ],
    "scripts": {
        "client": "yarn workspace frontend start",
        "client-test": "yarn workspace frontend test",
        "server": "yarn workspace backend start",
        "start": "conc --kill-others-on-fail \"yarn client\" \"yarn server\""
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "^7.6.0"
    }
}
```

And it always says: $ yarn workspace frontend test
**error Unknown workspace "frontend".**
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/workspace for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

I tried to start from all directories, nothing works

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that it does not matter how folders are called inside of "packages", the important thing is that package.json of each workspace should be called correspondingly:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
   ...
}
```